# Chi-Square test for homogeneity – Comparison between Sub-Samples

Tags: chi-squared-test, meta-analysis

I am conducting a meta-analysis and calculate the following chi-square statistics to test for homogeneity in the data. After forming two sub-samples - say, sub-sample A has a X² of 2,500 (df: 40) and sub-sample B has a X2 of 1,000 (df: 7) – I would like to test if one sub-sample is more homogenous than the other (along the line of a two-sample t-test). Is that possible and how would that work?

It might be a basic question, but I couldn’t find anywhere a satisfactory answer.

Many thanks for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Comparing values of $\chi^2$ is definitely not the way to go, you need $\tau^2$. You could fit a meta-regression with the variable which distinguishes your sub--samples as a binary moderator and do that twice, once allowing $\tau^2$ to vary between levels of the moderator and once with a common value of $\tau^2$. You can then compare the models. If you use R details on fitting can be found in the metafor package information pages [here](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:comp_two_independent_estimates)